# Subtracting dates in VBA using a for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a decision when the difference between two dates is greater than n number. The problem arises when I use a variable (`counter`) to refer to the row index, it returns a type mismatch and will not subtract from `Date`. If I substitute a number in for the variable `counter` it runs fine.

Why am I getting a mismatch error?

Why does it view the cell value differently when I call it with the variable even though the variable is equivalent to the number?

Thanks for the help.

```
Sub LoopTest()

Dim counter As Integer
    For counter = 1 To 5
        If Date - Cells(counter, 2) > 30 Then
            Range("H" & counter).Value = "working"
        End If        
    Next    

End Sub
```

Comment: does any of the `B1:B5` cells contain non-date value like text, blank, etc. ?

Comment: They're all dates. In fact I don't get an error if I write any specific number into the row index place holder instead of the variable 'counter'.

Comment: hmm strange .. you can try different variable name just in case, or `Date - Range("B" & counter)`

Comment: I've tried different variable names. In case it was the variable being named itself I tried it more simply with a: for each c in range ("B1:B3"), then referring to the value as c.value and it still has a mismatch error when subtracting from 'Date'.

Comment: You will get this error if the values in column B are strings that only _look_ like dates.  Ideally, fix your data so it's real dates.  Or use `If Date - DateValue(Cells(counter, 2)) > ...`

Comment: I agree with @chrisneilsen.  it is likely that one of your entries in column B is a "date in text clothing"  In some column, enter `=ISTEXT(B1)` and see if `TRUE` is returned for any of the entries.

Comment: This can be done with Formula instead of VBA.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and don't think this is the problem. IsText returns False for all data in the range. If I change formatting to general all dates are displayed in serial format...as I understand they should if they're recognized as dates. Additionally, if I step through the loop one number at a time substituting the number instead of the variable 'counter' for the 'row index' value within the Cell reference...it works. This would not work if the problem were the data not being in the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code below (I tested it with Dates, Numbers, Text and it worked)

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopTest()

Dim counter As Long

    For counter = 1 To 5
        If IsDate(Range("B" & counter).Value) Then
            If DateDiff("d", Date, Range("B" & counter).Value) > 30 Then
                Range("H" & counter).Value = "working"
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Well I'm stumped, it must be a formatting issue. This doesn't work but if I add an elseif IsDate() = False statement it tells me that they're not recognized as dates. I don't understand though, the dates in the sheet are even recognized in serial format. I feel like it shouldn't be this hard to have a program recognize a value as a date. I'm about to save it as .csv and have a python file parse it lol.

Comment: When I run this on a separate worksheet with manually entered dates it only returns a value on the last row and it doesn't appear to be calculating correctly.

Comment: Nvm, the variables Date and Cell value are just in wrong order in the DateDiff. It works. Now I just have to figure out why it won't work on my other sheet. Is there a way I can ask what each data type is when it fails? Or, alternatively, force a date type on the data? I tried the DateValue() from above and it did not work. Thanks.

Comment: You could try `Cdate` if it's a `String` constructed like a date

Comment: That didn't work either. Oddly enough I copy pasted all data into a new worksheet and everything works fine. Even my original code works. Not sure what was going on. Thank you for the help, and I will use your answer Shai, I like the utilization of the Datediff function, much cleaner looking. Thank you.